# Denormalizing table afterwards query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So far I had my `downloads` table denormalized. I had two fields - `author` and `country`. They were separated by a space, e.g.: `Jack James` as for `author` and `us uk` for `country`.

I decided it's time to normalize it so I made a new table called `downloads_authors` with fields (`da_id`, `downloads_id`, `da_author`, `da_country`) and now I have:

```
+-----+------------+---------+----------+
|da_id|downloads_id|da_author|da_country|
+-----+------------+---------+----------+
|1    |1           |Jack     |us        |
+-----+------------+---------+----------+
|2    |1           |James    |uk        |
+-----+------------+---------+----------+
```

So far so good.. but in the way I used to have them, I used `explode` and with a very bad function, I was getting the desired result - `<flag img> Jack, <flag img> James`

Now, when I have them in another table I cannot think of a way to do this:

`SELECT * FROM downloads` and list the respective author(s) without having an inner loop (because if I do a `JOIN` then I will have the information from `downloads` again and again).

Desired otuput is:

```
item 
- author
item 
- author
- author
```

Am I wrong about the `JOIN` and is it the way to go?

Comment: I would just query out all downloads then query out all authors. Loop over the downloads and assign them to an array where the download id is the key. Then loop over the authors and assign the different authors to a sub-array of the downloads using the download id.

Comment: But, @JonathanKuhn, considering that I have more than 2000 items at the moment and more than 6000 authors isn't it kind of a bad approach? Considering a page is visited at least 15-20 times per minute

Comment: Why would you list that many items on a single page? Paginate.

Comment: Based on how the join will output, I think your best bet is the multidimensional array.  For example: `$authors[$row[item]][] = $row[author]` then loop through the array as Jonathan suggested.

Comment: Your options are join and use the download information the first time you get a new download id and ignore the download information until you get a new download id. Or do what I said, query the data out and loop to build a new array. Or you could also use group_concat to join the authors together back into a single string.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn you can put that as an answer because exactly this is what I have done. I have used an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your options are join and use the download information the first time you get a new download id and ignore the download information until you get a new download id. Or do what I said, query the data out and loop to build a new array. Or you could also use group_concat to join the authors together back into a single string.

I would just query out all downloads then query out all authors. Loop over the downloads and assign them to an array where the download id is the key. Then loop over the authors and assign the different authors to a sub-array of the downloads using the download id.